# Replicating the drop-down ToolbarItem "More" in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, toolbaritems

I am struggling how I could replicate the drop-down `ToolbarItem` from `Xamarin.Forms` when a `ToolbarItem`'s order is set to `Secondary` for IOS, in order for it to look like it does for Android.

---

Here are some images to better explain what I am looking for:

**How it works on Android:**

1. Code:

```
ToolbarItem toolbarItem = new ToolbarItem()
{
  Text = "ToolbarItem",
  Order = ToolbarItemOrder.Secondary
};
```

2. Images on how it looks on Android:

**Image showing the "More" icon**

- [image: Image showing the "More" icon]

**Image showing the "More" icon expanded to show more toolbar items**

- [image: Image showing the "More" icon expanded to show more toolbar items]

There is no default "More" icon on the toolbar when setting the `Order` to `Secondary` in iOS. Instead what happens, is that a bar below the navigation bar is created, which includes all of the toolbar items - something I do not wish to have for my Application.

---

**This is an example of how it has been achieved before on IOS:**

**A screenshot I took from one of my Apps that implements this
   effect**

- [image: A screenshot I took from one of my Apps that implements this effect]

Comment: As you can see, many people are having this issue: https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/314600#Comment_314600

Comment: You can probably achieve this with a custom renderer.

Comment: @TreviAwater Please do explain how?

Comment: Might be a bit late but this might help out. github.com/SKLn-Rad/Xam.Plugin.PopupMenu

Comment: @PaulaKristin Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In native iOS, you can use [UIPopoverController](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/UIKit.UIPopoverController/) to achieve your effect. But please notice that this control can only be used in iPad.

Since you are using Xamarin.Forms, we can create a custom renderer in iOS platform to get this.

Firstly, create a page renderer to display the `UIPopoverController`. We can show it from a UIBarButtonItem or a UIView depending on your request. Here I use UIBarButtonItem like:

```
//I defined the navigateItem in the method ViewWillAppear
public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
{
    base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

    rightItem = new UIBarButtonItem("More", UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, (sender, args) =>
    {
        UIPopoverController popView = new UIPopoverController(new ContentViewController());
        popView.PopoverContentSize = new CGSize(200, 300);
        popView.PresentFromBarButtonItem(rightItem, UIPopoverArrowDirection.Any, true);
    });

    NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem.SetRightBarButtonItem(leftItem, true);
}
```

Secondly, construct the content ViewController in the UIPopoverController(just like the secondary list in android):

```
public class ContentViewController : UIViewController
{
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();

        UITableView tableView = new UITableView(new CGRect(0, 0, 200, 300));
        tableView.Source = new MyTableViewSource();
        View.AddSubview(tableView);
    }
}

public class MyTableViewSource : UITableViewSource
{
    public override UITableViewCell GetCell(UITableView tableView, NSIndexPath indexPath)
    {
        UITableViewCell cell = tableView.DequeueReusableCell(new NSString("Cell"));
        if (cell == null)
        {
            cell = new UITableViewCell(UITableViewCellStyle.Default, new NSString("Cell"));
        }

        cell.TextLabel.Text = "Item" + indexPath.Row;

        return cell;
    }

    public override nint RowsInSection(UITableView tableview, nint section)
    {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

At last we can show it on the screen by calling `PresentFromBarButtonItem`.

Comment: Hello, thank you so much for this response! I am self-taught and new to Xamarin, so please do excuse me if I sound ignorant. How would I go about  "creat[ing] a page renderer to display the UIPopoverController". I have followed the guides here, and have managed to make custom Renderers before using the examples that they have provided, but I cannot figure out how I would achieve the above mentioned. Just want to say thanks again for taking the time to write this answer, I really do appreciate it :)

Comment: When I said "here", I meant to add this link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/contentpage/

Comment: @Bracefor If you have managed to create a custom renderer, you can put my code above in the renderer. When you navigate to this page in forms. You can see the effect you want to achieve.

Comment: Okay, so could you maybe tell me then what files I should have where (the name of the file and in which folder it should be) Just to make sure I am doing it right?

Comment: @Bracefor the renderer is created at corresponding platform's project. One way you can check whether you are doing right is that override the `OnElementChanged` in the renderer file, then make a break point in this method. If project runs into this method, it means you have successfully made the renderer.

Comment: Yes, but I do not know what files to create where, and I do not fully understand the tutorial I mentioned above. @Land

Comment: @Bracefor I think you can read this documentation more carefully. And you can also download the sample, then run it to see which file should be created in which project. I think this will be more useful, because I don't know which file you metioned. please pay more attention to the attribute:`[assembly:ExportRenderer (typeof(CameraPage), typeof(CameraPageRenderer))]`